Is there a way to connect my private github repository to my folder on my Bluehost Cpanel?
I have a Private GitHub repository with PHP, HTML, Tailwind, and JS used in it. I have created an SSH with a passphrase,
my YAML file looked like this
name: CI/CD Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main  # Trigger deployment on push to the main branch

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up SSH
      uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.3
      with:
        ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

    - name: Add passphrase to SSH agent
      run: |
        echo "${{ secrets.SSH_PASSPHRASE }}" | ssh-add -  # Unlock the key with the passphrase

    - name: Sync files via SSH
      run: |
        rsync -avz --delete \
        -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" \
        ./ \
        username@server.com:/path/to/public_html/website/folderIWantToDeployTo/

    - name: Finalize Deployment
      run: |
        ssh username@server.com "cd /path/to/public_html/website/folderIWantToDeployTo/ && npm install"

and encountered this in my GitHub Actions:
deploy
Command failed: ssh-add - Enter passphrase for (stdin):

I also tried without a passphrase, updated my deploy.yml to this:
name: CI/CD Deployment

on: push: branches: - main

jobs: deploy: runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- name: Checkout code
  uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Set up SSH
  uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.3
  with:
    ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

- name: Sync files via SSH
  run: |
    rsync -avz --delete \
    -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" \
    ./ \
    username@server.com:/path/to/public_html/website/folderIWantToDeployTo/ 

- name: Finalize Deployment
  run: |
    ssh username@server.com "cd /path/to/public_html/website/folderIWantToDeployTo/ && npm install"

and got this in my github Actions:
deploy
Process completed with exit code 127.

PS: im using dummy data for the username, server and the path in this post.
All of these are stored in my repo settings> Secrets and variables
BLUEHOST_PASSWORD
BLUEHOST_SERVER
BLUEHOST_USERNAME
SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
SSH_PUBLIC_KEY
my ssh key is also stored in my repo settings > Deploy keys

It worked! The second solution without a passphrase ended up pushing my github private repository files to my folder on cpanel.
Few changes I did to the deploy.yml file was to save my username@server.com and folder path to my github secrets and variables, and add them as ${{secrets.MY_SERVER}} and ${{secrets.MY_PATH}}.
